# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (lines_white.png, line 0)

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, failed-to-load-viewstate

I was just wondering if anyone can let me know what I need to do... 
I've just created a new website through wordpress and the page loading speed was pretty slow so I decided to inspect elements and found an error saying "[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (lines_white.png, line 0)"

I've went to a website which tests my website and this file was taking more than 5~6 seconds sometimes 10 seconds to load...

I see that the file is in the /image/ but I don't know why it doesn't load..

Is there a way I can get rid of this .png file? so that it doesn't try to load when I open up the page?

Please let me know what I can do. Thank you.

-Jason

Additional info:

Edit "from the testing element, that's all I see "[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (lines_white.png, line 0)" and this is what I see in the page speed testing site "Response Headers 404

X-Pingbackhttp://www.neteffectrepair.com/xmlrpc.phpPragmano-cacheDateSat, 27 Sep 2014 06:06:58 GMTContent-EncodinggzipServerApacheVaryAccept-EncodingContent-Typetext/html; charset=UTF-8Cache-Controlno-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0ConnectioncloseContent-Length4709ExpiresWed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Request Headers

Pragmano-cacheAccept-CharsetISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3Accept-Encodinggzip,deflate,sdchHostwww.neteffectrepair.comAccept-Languageen-US,en;q=0.8User-AgentMozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31Accept*/*Refererhttp://www.neteffectrepair.com/Cookie__zlcmid=R2e5Y4aBUc5NkK; PHPSESSID=b9utohv5e503vftr37d35nb2a2Connectionkeep-aliveCache-Controlno-cache"

Comment: Where is the rest of the error message?

Comment: @rnevius I've posted an additional info at the bottom of my post. Please let me know if you need more information! Thanks!